# Restrict the execution of external binary programs through whitelist of allowed files

Tags: php, security

On a web server running PHP, I need the PHP scripts to be able to run one specific external program through `exec()`, `system()` or similar.
For that reason, the execution function must be enabled at PHP level.

However, to mitigate the impact of malicious PHP code I would like to limit the execution from PHP to the program needed only.

In other words, I don't want PHP to be able to run any (dangerous) program  found in the filesystem, such as /bin/ls, /usr/bin/wget and so on.

Edit: It's not a problem to trust or not the user input. I know that my PHP scripts runs the legitimate program. I worry about the capability offered to malicious PHP scripts to run everything through a shell exec.

It seems that PHP doesn't allow to specify the file names that can be executed, but is there any workaround to limit the execution? Maybe writing a customized PHP extension?

Comment: Or maybe an `if` statement that checks to see if a `GET` or `POST` variable is present, and if so, run the command you specify. Never allowing any user input to be placed inside the `exec`.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, but it's not a problem of trusting the user input. I know that my PHP scripts runs the legitimate program. I worry about the capability offered to malicious PHP scripts to run everything through a shell exec. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: i suck at nix* permissions but i could imagine that they could be configured so php could only run one program

Comment: could be a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584335/is-it-possible-to-restrict-what-commands-php-can-pass-through-exec-at-an-os-leve